# Using awk to match a string in a line and also match Nth line from first match

Tags: bash, git, shell, awk

`/tmp/foo` has the output of `git show` command, I need to find out ONLY the superproject changes, so I am trying to find the line with `+++` and 3'rd line from there matching `+Subproject commit`, and print the matches only, from the given /tmp/foo example, I like to print:

```
dir1 bcb1fe0dda395c82ac1fc8ec71fe87663e665147
dir2 3e56b818c92f7a0f7872abe37d30718a93ecda74
```

content of file /tmp/foo:

```
$ cat /tmp/foo
commit 8a47e9c8f210eca65e902c488cd356d4c00e992e
Author: name <email@google.com>
Date:   Thu Jun 14 16:30:05 2018 -0900

    Test

    Change-Id: Idb62494991d22fa59e66c22367a3770b95bb16

diff --git a/file.txt b/file.txt
index 610e336..c362aba 100644
--- a/file.txt
+++ b/file.txt
@@ -16,7 +16,8 @@
 #
 # A test
 #
-#  #..
+#  #....
+# This is a test
 #
 #
 #
diff --git a/dir1 b/dir1
index 1f98e97..ade1fe9 160000
--- a/dir1
+++ b/dir1
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit 1e25e071aef54240f5899a312dd3bee29150e607
+Subproject commit bcb1fe0dda395c82ac1fc8ec71fe87663e665147
diff --git a/dir2 b/dir2
index f54d099..3e99b81 160000
--- a/dir2
+++ b/dir2
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit f66c051f20b0948a5b8947456b516e870b54368e
+Subproject commit 3e56b818c92f7a0f7872abe37d30718a93ecda74
```

so far I tried this, I am sure I not doing it right. I need not necessarily use awk.

```
$ awk '/\+\+\+/{if(nr[NR+3] ~ /\+Subproject/){nr[NR+3];print nr[NR-3];print nr[NR]};next}; NR in nr'  /tmp/foo
 # A test
+Subproject commit bcb1fe0dda395c82ac1fc8ec71fe87663e665147
+Subproject commit 3e56b818c92f7a0f7872abe37d30718a93ecda74
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Adding a solution without using `getline` then following may help you.

```
awk '
/^\+\+\+/{
  sub(/.*\//,"",$NF);
  val=$NF;
  flag=1;
  count=""}
flag{
  count++;}
/^+Subproject commit/ && count==4{
  print val,$NF;
  flag=count="";
  next
}'  Input_file
```

---

---

Following `awk` may help you here.

```
awk '
/+++/{
  sub(/.*\//,"",$(NF-1));
  getline;
  getline;
  getline;
  if($0 ~ /^+Subproject commit/){
    print "dir"++count,$NF}
}'  Input_file
```

As per @Cyrus comment adding following too.

```
awk -F '[/ ]' '
/^\+\+\+/{
  dir=$NF;
  getline;
  getline;
  getline;
  if($0 ~ /^+Subproject commit/){
    print dir,$NF}
}'  Input_file
```

Comment: dir1 and dir2 is just an example, that could be any string.

Comment: @rodee, ok from where you are taking these strings?

Comment: I propose this change: `awk -F '[/ ]' '/^\+\+\+/ {dir=$NF; getline; getline; getline; if($0 ~ /^+Subproject commit/){print dir OFS $NF}}' file`

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, print nth line and n+3'th line only if n'th line starts with `+++` and n+3'th line starts with `+Subproject commit`

Comment: @rodee, please check my EDIT answer now.

Comment: @EdMorton, sure Ed done now, thanks for letting know.